# perl using function return value as if statement condition

Tags: perl, function, if-statement

Is it possible in Perl to use a function's return value as the expression in an "if" statement? For example; in C I can write

```c
if (!myFunction()){
   printf("myFunction returned false.\n");
} else {
   printf("myFunction returned true\n");
}
```

But in perl I find I must go through the pain of ..

```perl
$ret = myFunction();
if (!$ret){
    print "myFunction returned false.\n";
}
```

I know as soon as I post this someone will redirect me to several other posts of this question. But, obviously, I could not find what I'm looking for or I would not write this!
So spare me the "have you tried searching for ...." messages!

Here is what myFunction() looks like.

```
sub myFunction
{
    my ($run, $runTime) = @_;
    my ($code);

    eval {
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {die "Operation Timed Out";};

        alarm($run_time);
        $EXIT_STR = `$run`; # Execute $run and save output in EXIT_STR
        $code = $?;         # Save cmd exit code.
        $EXIT_CODE = $code; # Set a global value (EXIT_CODE)
        alarm(0);
        return($code);
    };
    if ($@) {
        if ($@ =~ /Operation Timed Out/) { 
            print "Time out\n";
            return(10);
        }
    }
}
```

After everyone's feedback I went back to the books to learn more about eval. After a bit of reading it was clearer that "eval" "returned" a value to the function it was part of. It was then up to me to decide what to do with the eval results. With that in mind I made some changes and the function works as I  had hoped. Thanks to all!

Comment: Yes, that works just fine in Perl. You didn't show us what your myFunction looks like, but the problem will be in there.

Comment: The extra variable is not required in perl.. what's the *real* problem? Make sure to include any actual messages/error indicators.

Comment: Can you show an example of a function that refuses to be used as an `if` condition?

Comment: Basically, "myFunction()" executes a command (via back ticks) and returns the command exit status ($?). However, my first example does not work (always executes the "true" portion of the statement when I know myFunction() is returning 0). My second example works as I expected the first example would. That is, $ret is 0 and the "false" portion of the statement is executed.

Comment: Please, show the EXACT example of `myFunction`. It simply works in perl, despite the long answers, it is mostly very intuitive. So, isn't possible to tell anything more without your code-example.

Comment: sub myFunction
{
    my ($run, $runTime) = @_;
    my ($code);

    eval {
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {die "Operation Timed Out";};

        alarm($run_time);
        $EXIT_STR = `$run`; # Execute $run and save output in EXIT_STR
        $code = $?;         # Save cmd exit code.
        $EXIT_CODE = $code; # Set a global value (EXIT_CODE)
        alarm(0);
        return($code);
    }
    if ($@) {
        if ($@ =~ /Operation Timed Out/) { 
            print "Time out\n";
            return(10);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Add the code for `myFunction` to your post by clicking the edit button. It's very difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: You know, if you have a `return` in an `eval` in a `sub`, the `return` doesn't return a value from the `sub` - it returns a value from the `eval`.

Comment: When you will use the recommended `use strict; use warnings;` you will catch the typo `$runTime` vs `$run_time`. You didn't return the result of `eval`. In the last if, what is returned when the `$@` isnt a `Timed out`? - many issues...

Comment: Obviously I'm new with "eval", and this was a quick (hand) edit of the original code to display here. So runTime is NOT an issue. The issue is what value is returned from the function. So, when I return from an eval, where I am returning to, the function body or the calling function?

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

Wait. I can't give such a short answer...

Yes. If a function is inside an if statement, Perl will take the return value of the function as a boolean value. If the return value is zero, a blank string, a null value, a null string, or an undef, the `if` statement will be considered false. Otherwise, the `if` statement will be considered true.

Here's an easy to understand example:

```
if ( not is_odd( $number ) ) {
    print "$number is divisible by two\n";
}

sub is_odd {
    my $number = shift;
    return $number % 2;   # Modulo arithmetic
}
```

In the above `$number % 2` will return zero on even numbers and one on odd numbers.

It's a good question. The best thing to do is to write a small script to try it out. Play around with it a bit:

For example. Let's add a second function we can use:

```
sub is_even {
    my $number = shift;
    return not is_odd( $number );
}
```

What does this return?  How does this work in an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

The only caveat is that using it in an if-statement will provide scalar context to the return value so if something non-scalar is returned, it will get scalarized before the if condition is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly return a false value in cases where you don't want the function to return True.  Remember that perl functions will return the last evaluated statement in the absence of a real return value.  So, take this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = 4;                                                                                                                            
my $y = 1;                                                                                                                            


if ( ! myFunction($x,$y) ) {
    print "myFunction returned false\n";
} else {
    print "myFunction returned true\n";
}

sub myFunction {
    my ($x,$y) = @_;
    my $response;

    if ( $x + $y == 2 ) {
        $response = "fun";
    } else {
        $response = "no fun";
    }
}
```

This will always print 'myFunction returned true' since either branch of the conditional is technically a true response.  However, if you add a return value to the negative branch of the conditional, it will now work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = 4;
my $y = 1;


if ( ! myFunction($x,$y) ) {
    print "myFunction returned false\n";
} else {
    print "myFunction returned true\n";
}

sub myFunction {
    my ($x,$y) = @_;
    my $response;

    if ( $x + $y == 2 ) {
        $response = "fun";
        return 1; # technically not really needed
    } else {
        $response = "no fun";
        return 0;
    }
}

$ perl test_funct.pl
myFunction returned false
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) for your subroutine from inside an [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).  This will not perform as you expect as explained in the docs for `return`:

> - `return EXPR`
> - `return`
>
>   Returns from a subroutine, [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), or [`do FILE`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) with the value given in EXPR. `...`

The bug you're facing can be demonstrated in the following example:

```
sub myFunction {
    eval {
        return "inside eval";
    };

    return "outside eval";
}

print myFunction();
```

Outputs:

```
outside eval
```

To fix your subroutine, assign your return value inside the eval, but actually return it from outside.  Also, be sure to localize your alarm signal handler.

```
sub myFunction {
    my ($run, $runTime) = @_;

    my $code;

    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {die "Operation Timed Out";};
        alarm($run_time);
        $EXIT_STR = `$run`; # Execute $run and save output in EXIT_STR
        alarm(0);
        $code = $?;         # Save cmd exit code.
    };

    if ($@) {
        if ($@ =~ /Operation Timed Out/) { 
            print "Time out\n";
            $code = 10;
        }
    }

    return $code;
}
```